# NUnit3 couldn't locate assembly "FSharp.Core 4.4.1.0" - Not used in rest of project

Tags: .net, tfs, package, nunit-3.0

I use NUnit3 to run all of my tests, and NUnit3TestAdapter within Visual Studio 2017. When running tests in a build on TFS i get the error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly
>   'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

All projects in my solution use FSharp.Core 4.5.2.0.

I've ensured that all projects use version 4.5.2.0, and have set up binding redirects to this version in all projects.

I've tried changing the reference to FSharp.Core in my test-project to use `4.4.1.0 (setting path to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.4.1.0\FSharp.Core.dll'`, and set the binding redirect in `app.config to 4.4.1.0` - but with no luck.

I had a similar issue that i fixed earlier.

> I had an error saying it couldn't load the assembly "nunit.framework,
>   Version=3.9.0.0"

At that point i was using version `3.11.0.0`, and fixed the issue by downgrading.

I've tried the same approach with `FSharp.Core`, but with no luck.

I'm using NUnit3TestAdapter 3.12.

I thought maybe NUnit3TestAdapter might just be dependent on "nunit.framework 3.9.0.0" and "FSharp.Core 4.4.1.0", but i haven't found anything about it when looking at documentation for NUnit3TestAdapter.

I've looked at related question and tried solutions by deleting `project\bin` and `project\obj` folders and building again.

Tests run fine in VS17 locally.

Is there a dependency for NUnit3TestAdapter that I'm not aware of, or might there be some package versions being inherited by other projects?

**EDIT:**
The reference to FSharp.Core in .fsproj:

> ```
>    <Reference Include="FSharp.Core">
>      <HintPath>..\packages\FSharp.Core\lib\net45\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
>      <Private>True</Private>
>      <Paket>True</Paket>
>    </Reference>
> ```

My references are:

**FSharp.Core**

**FsUnit.NUnit**

**mscorlib**

**nunit.framework**

**Nunit3.TestAdapter**

**System**

**System.Core**

**System.Numerics**

**Project A**

**Project B**

Comment: Could you check opening the `.csproj` and try to find whether any `FSharp.core` is referring that version ?

Comment: Could you also add the list of packages you are referencing in your test project? Have you included `Microsoft.Net.Test.SDK`?

Comment: Added package list and FSharp.Core reference in .fsproj.

Comment: Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk was not added before, but is now - no luck.

I tried to remove the binding redirect in my test project. I ran the tests in VS17, and all failed with the same warning "file or assembly "FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.1.0... could not be loaded".

I set the binding back to FSharp.Core 4.5.2, and the tests worked again - but still not in my TFS build.